# Use content security policy to avoid inline java script

Tags: apache, reactjs, nginx, content-security-policy

I have a use case where I serve my react application code form NGINX server which get its data from an apache server via post call in JSON format.

In this I am getting some content in my JSON data which REACT application will be rendering as tooltip and can contain HTML in it.

This tooltip content is taken as input from users and has vulnerability to inject some inline java script code. As there are multiple places (some non UI end point as well) which can inject such data and I don't want to sanitize input data at my apache server.

To handle this vulnerability I am planning to use **content security policy**  by setting header

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' *.mydomain.com
```

I am not sure where to set this header. Should I set it on response from my apache server or in my NGINX server before serving bundle.js for my react application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header needs to be applied to the response containing the HTML document representing the page.

Comment: but that will be just react based code with javascript and css. All data which will be rendered will come from apache server and that is the one which can contain inline js which can get executed.

Comment: @learner — You have a page (a), which loads some JS (b), which loads some more JS (c). The CSP has to be applied to the page (a) even if the JS (c) is loaded into it indirectly via (b). This is true even if it (a) fails to be [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and *just* loads a wodge of JavaScript (b).